# Social App message Tracking?

Tags: android

**Social App data access using SDK or without SDK/API :**

- I have found many android Apps, those are tracking message and all detail from the social app like Whats App, BBm, Viber chat etc.
- I search over googled as well as the developer site of all social apps. No one is provide any SDK or any API from you can track other user message  . {like : stealing}
- *Than I found on the **`Rooted device`** , you can do this, I searched but didn't get anything.*  If many apps tracking the other user detail i.e. this thing will happen.

`So, If those social App does not provide anything to do this than HOW IT CAN BE POSSIBLE ?`

**Can Someone correct me IF I wrote something worng ?**

or

**If this thing is possible, than please give some suggestion or way, `How it can be possible?`**

Thanks

Comment: what kind of msg ? your phone msges ? 
and social information can be extracted from social sdk like fb sdk .

Comment: whats App chat , Viber chat, BBM chat ..... @furqan

Comment: If I am not wrong you want to steal or get the msges which resides in viber or whatsapp app ?

Comment: hmm..... I found many apps those are doing this ... so I have a bit of curious that how it can be possible ? @furqan

Comment: All i know you cant access another app memory until your device is rooted .. Root device gives you the privillage to access all the thing then you can read and write everything

Comment: I also search but for the rooted I didnot find anything .. If you have any idea about how to start study for this , please let me know ... thanks @furqan

Comment: sure I will get back to you If I find anything :)

Comment: Can you give me an example of such an app? @AM

Comment: @BaapJamesBondKaBaap :a lot of are here ... one is below http://www.stealthgenie.com/features/whatsapp-spy.html

Answer (score 1):

If this is possible, it is most likely only possible if you're coding with C and using the NDK, since it gives low level access, and kind of bypasses the basic Java coding restrictions. Like turning on settings without any user interaction. I hope this helps in any way.

Comment: have you any idea to start with this ?

Comment: it'll help a lot for the start or get understand. how other did this thing ?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but if you want to have more access than a standard Java app has, you can try this. There's bound to be a tutorial on accessing the data on your phone (without rooting) via C. I would by searching for that

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at them individually. E.g there is a [good research on whatsapp.](http://geeknizer.com/read-extract-whatsapp-messages-android-iphone-blackberry/) .

You just need to get the access to their database, if they are using sqlite, you can directly get their database and run queries on them. Sqlite Browser or other GUI sqlite tools will be helpful in checking their db schema.

Comment: Did you get the whatsapp dataabase? They might have changed the encryption

Comment: In most others all you just need to get the database file. It's usually in /data/data/<package_name>/database

Comment: yes, I get the database from this path and tried it also but it'll not giving the o/p.. you are right might have changed in the encryption or something else

Comment: I am curious about that how can all app are doing this... ? May be something will get for the start... :)